# C#: Out of memory during dotnet build after migrate to NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, out-of-memory, .net-5

We use `App Buddy` as our CI/CD system. Today we migrate project from `ASP.NET Core 3.1` to `NET 5`. After that dotnet build start consuming a lot of RAM (allocate about 10-12GB) and we dont have as much memory on our server.

On our CI/CD server during `dotnet build` we get `Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(71,5): error : Process terminated. System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`

I've tried use `-maxCpuCount:1` but it doesn't work. Is it any possibility to limit memory which `dotnet build` can use?

Comment: Related to this perhaps? https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/1846

Comment: Can you share your dotnet build command?
Try to use `dotnet msbuild /maxcpucount:1` instead `dotnet build` in some cases it helps to avoid mysterious problems with build properties

Comment: @LeonidPavlov i mentioned in post that it doesn't work in my case

Comment: @WojciechRak I saw that you used `dotnet build`, I suggest using `dotnet msbuild`

Comment: @LeonidPavlov unfortunately it also doesn't work:
`dotnet msbuild project.csproj /maxcpucount:1 /p:RestorePackages=false /p:BuildProjectReferences=false /p:Configuration=Release`
`Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.0+0538acc04 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`

`/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.401/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(71,5): error : Process terminated. System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After almost one week of searching with team. We find a way to reduce ram consumption during build. We solve it by adding `-p:RunAnalyzers=false` and it help a lot! Other solutions didn't work.

```
dotnet build "project" -p:RunAnalyzers=false
```

We can also disable this in csproj (and not run analyzers in VS, but it not good idea in my opinion).

It's not 100% solving problem, but it allows us to run build, so I will not run analyzer by the time I find solution to limit ram usage of msbuild

Comment: do you have any more info on this? did you find anything to do with limiting ram usage of msbuild or similar?

Comment: did you find any other solution on this?

Comment: unfortunately no :(